# Getting "No Route matches" error when though I have a method in my controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration, routes

I’m using Rails 4.2.3.  I have this in my controller file, “./app/controllers/users_controller.rb” …

```
  def edit
    @user = User.find(session["user_id"])
    render 'edit'
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(session["user_id"])
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
    end
    render 'edit'
  end
```

And I have this in my “./app/views/users/edit.html.erb” file

```
    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
    …
        <%= button_to "Save", { :action => "update" }, :method => :post, :class => 'button' %>
```

But when I visit my url “http://localhost:3000/users/edit”, I get this error

```
No route matches {:action=>"update", :controller=>"users"}
```

This is what I have in routes/config.rb so I’m not sure why its falling apart …

```
  get "users/edit" => "users#edit"
  resources :users
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to use PUT/PATCH method for the update action, while POST is used for the create action as per the Rails [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions):

```
    <%= button_to "Save", { :controller => "users", :id => @user.id }, :method => :put, :class => 'button' %>
```

Also, [`rake routes`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#listing-existing-routes) is a really useful command for debugging routing issues that dumps all defined routes.

Comment: I changed my button code to "<%= button_to "Save", { :action => "update" }, :method => :put, :class => 'button' %>" but when I visit http://localhost:3000/users/edit, I still get the same error.

Comment: @Dave Updated answer - try passing `{ :controller => "users", :id => @user.id }`. Unfortunately, can't test, but that should work.

Comment: Also looked at your code again -- you could use `f.submit` instead, i.e. `<%= form_for(@user, :method => :put) do |f| %>` and then `f.submit` instead of `button_to`.